# Error al utilizar etiqueta en PLSQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Estoy intentando utilizar etiquetas para poder realizar una serie de secuencias en un procedimiento PLSQL pero al compilar me aparece el siguiente error, el ejemplo lo realice de acuerdo con la información que encontré en documentacion de Oracle.

[PL/SQL Control Structures](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/04_struc.htm)

-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo "<" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:

( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with 
     <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
   json_exists json_value json_query json_object json_array
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

```
DECLARE
    PRIMERDIA   DATE;
    ULTIMODIA   DATE;
BEGIN
    <<DATOS>> 
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 1), 'MM'),
            LAST_DAY(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 1)))
        INTO
            PRIMERDIA,
            ULTIMODIA
        FROM
            DUAL;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(PRIMERDIA
                             || ' '
                             || ULTIMODIA);
    END;

    GOTO DATOS;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Oracle 11g, la llamada y la etiqueta están funcionando bien.
Pero en un loop infinito, te puede llegar a llenar el buffer, y probocar un error de "buffer overflow".
Dejo ejemplo para cortar la secuencia y para evitar el overflow, y el salto a la etiqueta funciona correctamente.

```
    DECLARE
    PRIMERDIA   DATE;
    ULTIMODIA   DATE;
    CONTADOR   NUMBER :=0;
BEGIN
   <<DATOS>> 
BEGIN

    SELECT
        TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 1), 'MM'),
        LAST_DAY(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 1)))
    INTO
        PRIMERDIA,
        ULTIMODIA
    FROM
        DUAL;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(PRIMERDIA
                         || ' '
                         || ULTIMODIA);
    CONTADOR:=CONTADOR+1;
END;

  IF CONTADOR<10 THEN
    GOTO DATOS;
  END IF;

END;
```